# Name resolution doesn't work, but nslookup does

Tags: solaris, dns

I am having a very strange problem with my installation of Solaris 11. DNS resolution just won't work, but strangely enough, nslookup does and connectivity is fine:

```
root@solarisxyz:~# ping stackexchange.com
ping: unknown host stackexchange.com
root@solarisxyz:~# nslookup stackexchange.com
Server:         10.x.x.x (DNS)
Address:        10.x.x.x#y

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stackexchange.com
Address: 64.34.119.12

root@solarisxyz:~# ping 64.34.119.12
64.34.119.12 is alive
```

Relevant sections of files:

- **/etc/resolv.conf**: (this is the same thing our Linux boxes have)

  ```
  domain us.oracle.com
  nameserver 10.x.x.x
  nameserver 10.x.x.x
  ```
- **/etc/hosts**:

  ```
  # ::1 solarisxyz localhost (commented out)
  127.0.0.1 localhost loghost solarisxyz
  ```
- **/etc/nsswitch.conf**:

  ```
  hosts:    files dns
  # pretty much everything else set to files
  ```

Comment: In `resolv.conf`, is it actually `10.x.x.x` or did you hide the IP address?

Comment: @amphetamachine The actual address is correct and reachable via ping.

Comment: Could you please compare the output of these commands:
`dig @10.x.x.x stackexchange.com`
`dig @8.8.8.8 stackexchange.com`
`dig stackexchange.com`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Network configuration has radically changed starting with Solaris 11. nsswitch.conf is only informative now.
Assuming you are not in automatic mode, in which case DNS would have been correctly configured, here is the new procedure:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E24456/gliyc.html#OSTELgllcu

Comment: So basically editing files like `nsswitch.conf` has no effect whatsoever on network configuration now?

Comment: Indeed, nsswitch.conf is now managed by smf just like resolv.conf and many other /etc configuration files. You should refer to their manual pages for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Configuring Naming Services by Using SMF

The following example shows how to configure DNS by using SMF commands.

```
# svccfg
svc:> select dns/client
svc:/network/dns/client> setprop config/search = astring: \
("us.company.com" "eu.company.com" "companya.com" "companyb.com" "company.com" )
svc:/network/dns/client> setprop config/nameserver = net_address: \
( 138.2.202.15 138.2.202.25 )
svc:/network/dns/client> select dns/client:default
svc:/network/dns/client:default> refresh
svc:/network/dns/client:default> validate
svc:/network/dns/client:default> select name-service/switch
svc:/system/name-service/switch> setprop config/host = astring: "files dns"
svc:/system/name-service/switch> select system/name-service/switch:default
svc:/system/name-service/switch:default> refresh
svc:/system/name-service/switch:default> validate
svc:/system/name-service/switch:default> 
# svcadm enable dns/client
# svcadm refresh name-service/switch
# grep host /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:  files dns
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: I hate this system. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem has something to do with the Solaris Name Service daemon or more correctly the configuration of this beast. Perhaps you have edited /etc/nsswitch.conf by hand? This would explain why the Name Service daemon does not pick up upon it.

The nslookup command does not - afaik - use the Solaris Name Service. This might explain why you see nslookup working as you expect while everything else is not.

On Solaris it is always a good idea to verify if the lookup services are working as you expect by using the `getent` command. In your example it would be:

```
getent hosts stackexchange.com
```

So the question is how to make sure the Solaris Name Service knows that it has to lookup host names in both local files **as well as** in DNS. Remember that in Solaris 11 you are no longer supposed to / allowed to edit files such files as /etc/nsswitch.conf directly. They are controlled by daemons that run under SMF. Here is how to change it:

```
# svccfg
svc:> select name-service/switch
svc:/system/name-service/switch> setprop config/host = astring: "files dns"
svc:/system/name-service/switch> select system/name-service/switch:default
svc:/system/name-service/switch:default> refresh
svc:/system/name-service/switch:default> validate
svc:/system/name-service/switch:default> exit
# svcadm refresh name-service/switch
```

After this you will notice that your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file has been re-written to disk. If you have previously edited by hand you may not see any actual change. Re-issue the `getent` command and hopefully it works now.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For Solaris 10, I did `svcadm restart /system/name-service-cache`; then, I can resolve host using telnet/ping.

Answer (score 1):

First please start `truss` on `nscd`:

```
truss -aefld -vall -wall -rall -o truss-nscd.out -u nss_\*:: -u libnsl:: -p `pgrep nscd`
```

While the above `truss` command is running, please try

```
truss -aefld -vall -wall -rall -o truss-getent_1.out -u a.out,libnsl:: getent hosts ANY_HOSTNAME
```

Then please temporarily disable `nscd`:

```
svcadm disable name-service-cache
```

and run:

```
truss -aefld -vall -wall -rall -o truss-getent_2.out -u a.out,libnsl:: -u nss_\*:: getent hosts ANY_HOSTNAME
```

Now you may re-enable name-service-cache:

```
svcadm enable name-service-cache
```

Now try ...hope it will works.