# Why `host` and `nslookup` on Solaris 10 resolves hostnames while `ping` and `telnet` does not?

Tags: solaris, dns

- `/etc/resolv.conf` contains a nameserver that is alive (as reported by the `ping` command)
- `host` or `nslookup` is able to resolve `google.com`

  ```
  $ host google.com
  google.com has address 74.125.228.3
  google.com has address 74.125.228.4
  ...
  $ nslookup google.com
  ...
  Non-authorative answer:
  Name:   google.com
  Address: 74.125.228.0
  Name:   google.com
  Address: 74.125.228.1
  ..
  ```
- `ping` or `telnet` is not able to resolve `google.com`

  ```
  $ ping google.com
  ping: unknown host google.com
  $ telnet google.com
  google.com: node name or service name not known
  ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems `ping` and `telnet` were unable to resolve hostnames, because they were not querying the configured DNS server (`host` and `nslookup` seem to be using different DNS querying code), the solution is to:

Overwrite `/etc/nsswitch.conf` with `/etc/nsswitch.dns`:

```
cp /etc/nsswitch.dns /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Comment: Ideally you should copy /etc/nsswitch.dns over to /etc/nsswitch.conf, this is the normal and documented way to set up your system to use DNS, among creating the /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: It also depends how you installed Solaris. If at the interactive installer, or in sysidcfg, you specify DNS, nsswitch.conf should already be configured properly.

Comment: @AlexandreAlves Thanks, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman Since I have very little experience with Solaris, I admit that maybe I missed it during the installation. But still it is really surprising that this is not set by default.

Comment: @AdamSiemion keep in mind that many of Solaris' largest customers are closed environments where DNS may not necessarily be used, and instead NIS holds sway. (or LDAP sometimes).  Sun used to focus most of it's energy on it's top 50 customers.  DNS stuff was added for the rest of their customers, but not made the default, because revenue from the top 50 > the rest.  Oracle likely plays a similar game.

Answer (score 4):

Adam, you do not tell us what version of Solaris you're using.

All host lookup on Solaris goes through the Solaris Naming Service daemon. The only exception is `nslookup` which does a direct DNS query against a DNS server. The Naming Service daemon basically acts as a cache of naming information. Other operating systems have similar services. The Solaris Naming Service is configured in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file.

I really, really hope you are on an older version, such as Solaris 10 or before. Otherwise you've now manually edited a file you are no longer supposed to edit : the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file.

Anyway, lets say you are on **Solaris 10** or older:
Your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` should have an entry like this:

```
hosts:  files dns
```

This tells the Solaris Naming Service that hosts should be looked up *first* in the local file (i.e. `/etc/hosts`) and *then* in DNS. You can of course also only have "dns" here but people will normally want it so that `/etc/hosts` can override what is in DNS.

You may now have to restart the naming service daemon:

```
svcadm restart /system/name-service-cache
```

You can always verify your naming service setup with the Solaris `getent` command:

```
getent hosts google.com
```

The `getent` command verifies that the Solaris Naming Service works as you expect. You *cannot* use `nslookup` to verify this.

If your are on **Solaris 11** then you can use nolan600's answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24928/name-resolution-doesnt-work-but-nslookup-does%20vvv). The `getent` command also applies to Solaris 11.

Hope you can use some of this.

Comment: `/usr/bin/host` is another exception as it's a direct DNS client and does not use the Solaris name services.

Answer (score 0):

```
root@solaris:~# svccfg -s name-service/switch
svc:/system/name-service/switch> setprop config/host = "files dns"
svc:/system/name-service/switch> listprop config
config                      application
config/default             astring     files
config/value_authorization astring     solaris.smf.value.name-service.switch
config/printer             astring     "user files"
config/host                astring     "files dns"
svc:/system/name-service/switch> exit
root@solaris11:~# svcadm refresh name-service/switch
```

Comment: you can also update the DNS if there's still an issue solaris 10&11

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Pasting some code do not make it good answer